# Update button on stock management system not working, MySQL, Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

The update button on my simple stock management system is not updating the stock. When clicked it shows the product updated dialog but nothing happens. It is throwing no errors and i cant find the problem.

It was working when i only had 5 rows but when i added the category and quantity row it stopped.

```java
private void btn_updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        if(checkInputs() && txt_id.getText() != null)
        {
            String UpdateQuery = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            Connection con = getConnection();

            //update without image
            if(ImgPath == null)
            {
                try {
                    UpdateQuery = "UPDATE products SET name = ?, price = ?"
                            + ", add_date = ?, category = ?, quantity = ?, WHERE id = ?";
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);

                    ps.setString(1, txt_name.getText());
                    ps.setString(2, txt_price.getText());

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String addDate = dateFormat.format(txt_AddDate.getDate());

                    ps.setString(3, addDate);

                    ps.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText()));

                    String value = combo_category.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    ps.setString(5, value);

                    ps.setString(6, txt_quantity.getText());


                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    Show_Products_In_JTable();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product Updated");

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
            //update with Image
            else{
                try{
                InputStream img = new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath));

                UpdateQuery = "UPDATE products SET name = ?, price = ?"
                            + ", add_date = ?,image = ?, category = ?, quantity = ?, WHERE id = ?";

                    ps = con.prepareStatement(UpdateQuery);

                    ps.setString(1, txt_name.getText());
                    ps.setString(2, txt_price.getText());

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    String addDate = dateFormat.format(txt_AddDate.getDate());

                    ps.setString(3, addDate);

                    ps.setBlob(4, img);

                    String value = combo_category.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    ps.setString(5, value);


                    ps.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText()));

                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    Show_Products_In_JTable();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product Updated");

            }catch(Exception ex)      
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One or More Fields Are Empty Or Wrong");
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight

```
quantity = ?, WHERE id = ?
```

shoule be

```
quantity = ? WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: sorry i changed that already, i just pasted the old code by accident. does anything else stick out at you?

Comment: @vctburk Yeah in your else,you have 7 parameters and you pass only 6.

Comment: sorry for being ignorant but could you be more specific. what should i change. thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Those `?` are parameters - you set them,for example first one  `ps.setString(1, txt_name.getText());` There should be 7,you stop at 6.